# How can I set the default page in Visual Studio for a mvc3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

Before I changed the default page of my project, when I would run it, its url was same:

> ```
>       http://localhost:54465
> ```

and it loaded default home page.

after I set "Index" as  default page, its url changed to:

> ```
>      http://localhost:54465/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> ```

it shows this error:

> "The resource cannot be found."

and doesn't show home page.

How can I change it to the default setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't set `.cshtml` views as Default Page. In ASP.NET MVC Views cannot be served directly. Requests go through the routing engine which resolves controllers and actions. It is those actions that are returning views. So if you want to set a default action you could configure it in the properties of the ASP.NET MVC Project by specifying the URL to launch when running the project. It is situated in the `Web` tab:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work for me: In the **Web** tab, select the **Specific Page** radio button, but leave the field next to it blank.

Comment: Yes, if you leave it blank it launches `/` which in terms routes by default to `Home/Index`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do you have some other questions on this topic or you might consider closing it by marking an answer?

Comment: Thanx all. I deleted content of field next to Specific Page and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

MVC architecture does not support to set a default page with extension, so remove the extension  ( Login/userLogin) and save the web tab, it will be work fine.